# Returning and printing specific parts of a list to user based on user input

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm trying to create a program that allows a user to select a car insurance to learn various things about them and I'm stuck on actually displaying the insurance the user picked. Attached is a picture of the running code and where it stops. Any help would be appreciated!

```
astate = 'Allstate'
pro = 'Progressive'
sfarm = 'State Farm'
lmut = 'Libery Mutual'
gei = 'Geico'

insurance = [astate, pro, sfarm, lmut, gei]

ins = {

    astate: [

    ('The average price of insurance for Males using Allstate is:\nMale Teen: $2,137\nMale Adult: $1,819\nMale Senior: $1,468\nThe average price of insurance for Females using Allstate is:\nFemale Teen: $1,889\nFemale Adult: $1,759\nFemale Senior: $1,447\nThe average car insurance rating for Allstate is: 4.02')

    ],

    pro: [

    ('The average price of insurance for Males using Allstate is:\nMale Teen: $2,953\nMale Adult: $1,523\nMale Senior: $1,190\nThe average price of insurance for Females using Allstate is:\nFemale Teen: $2,706\nFemale Adult: $1,575\nFemale Senior: $1,143\nThe average car insurance rating for Allstate is: 4.05')

    ],

    sfarm: [

    ('The average price of insurance for Males using Allstate is:\nMale Teen: $1,967\nMale Adult: $1,418\nMale Senior: $1,062\nThe average price of insurance for Females using Allstate is:\nFemale Teen: $1,721\nFemale Adult: $1,418\nFemale Senior: $1,062\nThe average car insurance rating for Allstate is: 4.12')

    ],

    lmut: [

    ('The average price of insurance for Males using Allstate is:\nMale Teen: $3,199\nMale Adult: $2,862\nMale Senior: $2,588\nThe average price of insurance for Females using Allstate is:\nFemale Teen: $2,625\nFemale Adult: $2,845\nFemale Senior: $2,583\nThe average car insurance rating for Allstate is: 3.94')

    ],

    gei: [

    ('The average price of insurance for Males using Allstate is:\nMale Teen: $1,492\nMale Adult: $1,204\nMale Senior: $1,088\nThe average price of insurance for Females using Allstate is:\nFemale Teen: $1,460\nFemale Adult: $1,200\nFemale Senior: $1,079\nThe average car insurance rating for Allstate is: 4.13')

    ]

}

def ins_option():

    while True:
        try:
            ins_num = int(input('Please select the car insurance you want information on:\n1 for {}\n2 for {}\n3 for {}\n4 for {}\n5 for {}\nChoice:'.format(astate, pro, sfarm, lmut, gei)))
        except ValueError:
            print("Your input is not a number, please try again.\n")
        else:
            if 0 >= ins_num or ins_num > len(ins):
                print("Invalid value, please try again.\n")
            else:
                return ins_num

option = ins_option()
ins_name = insurance[option - 1]

print("\n Ok, here is information about {}:\n".format(ins_name))
```

[Program Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Czc.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your question why the information(Average Price ,Male, Teen ...) is not showing ?
Your Last line's print statement doesn't include the information. 
Convert the last line to :

`print("\n Ok, here is information about {}:\n {}".format(ins_name,ins[ins_name][0]))`